# Correct way to implement bootstrap popover with ajax request

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to implement Bootstrap's popover which will appear after response for AJAX request will be received.

Here is HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>
            <strong>Sorted laptops:</strong>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-7">
        <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-loading-text="Generating link to share, please wait..." id="share_results">Share results</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is JS code:

```
$('#share_results').click(function(event) {
    var $share_results, delimiter, descriptions, query;
    $share_results = $(this);
    $share_results.button('loading');
    descriptions = $.map($('td.laptop_desc'), function(val) {
        return $(val).text().trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
    });
    delimiter = $('#delimiter').val();
    query = descriptions.join(' ' + delimiter + '\n\n');
    $.post('/path', {
        'query': query,
        'delimiter': delimiter
    }, function(resp) {
        var content, hash, url;
        $share_results.button('reset');
        hash = resp['hash_string'];
        url = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?q=' + hash;
        content = "<input class='form-control input-sm' value='" + url + "'>";
        return $share_results.popover({
        container: '.container',
        html: true,
        delay: 500,
        placement: 'left',
        'content': content
        }).popover('show');
    });
});
```

No CSS changes were made.

Initial button state:

[image: Initial button state]

State after request is received:

[image: State after request is received]

Here I am having two problems:

- popover always on top - doesn't disappear
- popover width is too small

How to fix that?

Comment: It'll be a bit hard to tell what may be going wrong if we don't also have your HTML and any relevant CSS....

Comment: added HTML code, no changes were made to CSS